# laravel-5.2 pagination not working - undefined method stdClass::links() error

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I am not able to display laravel pagination. it gives me an error undefined method stdClass::links() I have used render method but yet gives me an error undefined method stdClass::render()

here is my code

```
<?php $products = DB::table('products')->where('category_id',$category-> id)->paginate(4); ?>



@foreach($products as $products)
    <li class="product-item col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="product-inner">
            <div class="thumb has-second-image">
                <a href="#">
                        @if(empty($products-> medium_product_image))
                            {{ HTML::image('images/no-image.gif',$products-> product_name) }}
                        @else
                            {{ HTML::image($products-> medium_product_image,$products-> product_name) }}
                        @endif
                </a>
            </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3 class="product-name short"><a href="#">{{ $products-> product_name }}</a></h3>
                    <span class="price">{{ $products-> product_price }}</span>
                    <del>{{ $products-> product_old_price }}</del>
                </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach



<nav class="pagination navigation">
<ul class="page-numbers">
    <li>{!! $products-> links() !!}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute your query in the view?

Comment: where is `$category-> id` ? try with hardcoded id ?

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty yes i am doing this in a view

Comment: @Rishi yes its a hardcoded id

Comment: can you update first what actually your code looks like ? it seems like `$category-> id` was missing.

Comment: Are you getting `$products` value?

Comment: @Rishi yes i am getting those values . when i use ->get() instead of ->paginate(4) i am getting all the values , when i use ->paginate(4) it shows me 4 products but when i add {!! $products-> links() !!} it gives me an error undefined method stdClass::links()

Comment: can you check your app.php for `Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,` ?

Comment: use {{ $products->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() }} instead of {!! $products-> links() !!}

Comment: @Rishi yes its der

Comment: @KevinPatel Call to undefined method stdClass::appends() error again :(

Comment: can u describe which Illuminate libraries  incluse in your controller . 
i use this two use 
     Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
     use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

Comment: @KevinPatel I havnt used any Illuminate libraries for pagination after your comment i added those libraries yet giving me same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change this line @foreach($products as $products) to something like @foreach($products as $product) . I think error is Due to same variable name

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 {!! $products->render() !!}
```

Instead of

```
 {!! $products-> links() !!}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::render() not working :(